# Can I make a component transparent without hiding it?

Tags: java, user-interface, codenameone, transparency

I need to make a component transparent, so there's nothing to see, but it still takes its place (unlike with `setVisible(false)`).

With CSS terminology, I need `visibility:hidden` rather than `display:none`.

Ideally, it should work for any component, including containers and their children. So I don't think, subclassing and overriding `paint` or alike is the way to go.

- Replacing by other component and delegating could do, will it?
- Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setVisible()` hides a component while it still occupies its space unlike `setHidden()` which shrinks the component away`. See:

```
Form hi = new Form("Visible", BoxLayout.y());

Button r1 = new Button("Regular");
Button invisible = new Button("Invisible");
invisible.setVisible(false);
Button r2 = new Button("Regular");

Button r3 = new Button("Regular");
Button hidden = new Button("Hidden");
hidden.setHidden(true);
Button r4 = new Button("Regular");

hi.add(BoxLayout.encloseX(r1, invisible, r2));
hi.add(BoxLayout.encloseX(r3, hidden, r4));

hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: That's nice! I was relying on my memory when asking... and it was wrong. Actually, I need both `setHidden` and `setVisible`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to take the component that you want to sometimes be transparent (call it "trans") and place it in another JPanel ("holder"), then place holder where you would have placed trans.

To make things transparent, set holder's preferred size equal to trans's preferred size, and set the visibility of trans to false, and revalidate the parent of holder.

Comment: Hi, this question is related to [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) not Swing.